# jQuery scrollbar spacing issue

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

This is definitely a newbie issue but I was wondering how to add padding to the jQuery scrollbar do that there is more spacing between the scrollbar and the mainContent text (maybe padding is the wrong property for this? maybe margin?). I keep trying to add padding to different css rules to the jquery.jscrollpane.css (trying to use trial and error here) and the scrollbar wont move further away from the text.

Comment: Can you post your html and jquery please? You can use the 'code' toolbar button or indent four spaces to automatically block and syntax highlight the code.

Comment: http://martinezcelaya.com/pub.html

Comment: the scrollbar is working which is great but i am hoping to space it away from the text maybe 5 or 10px... any tips for me? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content seems to be contained in `<div class="jspPane" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; width: 529px; top: -434.14428571428573px; ">` I'd suggest instead of `padding-right:0;` changing it to maybe `padding-right:5px;`.

Either add it on there or whatever you have specified in your HTML to hold the text, I believe it's either `#mainContent` or `.scroll-pane`.

Comment: ya i used firebug at first to try to figure it out and saw those lines of code however in the jquery.jscrollpane.css file i dont see that at all for .jspPane..... i have copied and pasted below the first 37 lines of the css file so you can see what i do:

Comment: /*
 * CSS Styles that are needed by jScrollPane for it to operate correctly.
 *
 * Include this stylesheet in your site or copy and paste the styles below into your stylesheet - jScrollPane
 * may not operate correctly without them.
 */

.jspContainer
{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.jspPane
{
 position: absolute;
 padding-right: 5px;
}

.jspVerticalBar
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 8px;
 height: 100%; 
}

.jspHorizontalBar
{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 16px;
 background: red;
}

Comment: .jspContainer
{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.jspPane
{
 position: absolute;
}

.jspVerticalBar
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 8px;
 height: 100%; 
}

.jspHorizontalBar
{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 16px;
 background: red;
}

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar and content are both absolutely positioned. So adding padding or margins just increases their width, but have no affect relative to one another. You need to change the actual width of the elements. The following should work.

```
.jspPane { width: 500px; }
```

Update, actually that won't work. The width is specified as an inline style. If you have manual control over this then you should edit it yourself. If this is set by jscrollpane then you will need to find an api that allows you to specify the content width.